# How to run Autokey without root privileges?

Tags: autokey

I made some shortcuts using autokey-gtk and they worked fine. However, I need to run them on a computer that I don't have root privileges, so I can't install it using `apt`.

*What I've tried*:

- I cloned the repo from git (I cant install it, it requires root permission)
- Succesully installed `pip3 autokey` (I don't know how to use it)

How do I run the shortcut, having `shortcut.py` and `.shortcut.json`?

(In specific, those [shortcuts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1122368/how-to-set-f3-f4-and-f6-to-copy-paste-and-cut))

Comment: Using autokey does not require root permissions. Give some more info: does autokey otherwise work, i.e., does it work if you create a new shortcut or abbreviation? Does your script that does not work do something special?

Comment: If you do not own the system you need to ask the admin of that server.

Comment: @vanadium It is just a shortcut for F3 copy, F4 paste, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1122368/how-to-set-f3-f4-and-f6-to-copy-paste-and-cut

Comment: @Rinzwind I gave more information about the problem. Can't I run autokey with only having installed it via pip3?

Comment: I cannot help with Autokey which I stopped using long time ago, but for this specific application, it will by by far easiest just to use a keyboard simulation tool like ydotool (work on Xorg, but also on Wayland) or xdotool (Xorg only, so (like Autokey) not future proof. I will add some info instructions in your other question.